# Allow horizontal overlapping divs only when width of parent is inadequate

Tags: css, flexbox

A variable quantity of 'inner' divs will be generated and placed inside their relevant 'middle' div parent. When the number of 'inner' divs is enough to fit inside the parent I have no problem. However, when there are too many to fit, I would like them to overlap each other, by the minimum amount possible. I cannot use 'position absolute' on the 'inner' div as the amount of the overlap is not known at the time the code is generated.

I have tried using `flex-shrink: 1;`. I also tried to use 'inline-block', but 'inner' either tries to overflow or wrap. Is there anyway this can be done without knowing how many inner divs there are. The 'middle' div needs to be positioned absolute as this will have a variable value from the top of the page.

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.middle {
  min-width: 80px;
  max-width: 80px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {

  min-height: 1.2rem;
  border: .1rem solid red;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
  vertical-align: middle;

}
```

```html
  <div class="middle" style="justify-content: flex-start;left: 0;top: 0;">
    <div class="inner">A</div>
    <div class="inner">A</div>
    <div class="inner">A</div>
    <div class="inner">A</div>
    <div class="inner">A</div>
    <div class="inner">A</div>
    <div class="inner">A</div>
  </div>

  <div class="middle" style="justify-content: flex-end;left: 0;top: 50px;">
    <div class="inner">A</div>
    <div class="inner">A</div>
  </div>
```

[image]

[JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ehq54730/4/)

Answer (score 1):

If you add an extra wrapper for your divs you can do it like below:

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.middle {
  min-width: 80px;
  max-width: 80px;
  background-color: #eee;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}

.inner { 
  /* for the upper container to shrink */
  flex-shrink: 1;
  min-width:0;
  /**/
  direction:rtl; /* align to the right */
}
.inner:first-child {
  flex-shrink:0; /* don't shrink the first one */
}
.inner > div {
  min-height: 1.2rem;
  border: .1rem solid red;
  display:inline-block; /* this is important to get the width of the content */
  background:lightblue;
  direction:ltr; /* reset the alignment for the content */
}
```

```html
<div class="middle" style="max-width:200px">
    <div class="inner"><div>A</div></div>
    <div class="inner"><div>A</div></div>
    <div class="inner"><div>A</div></div>
    <div class="inner"><div>A</div></div>
    <div class="inner"><div>A</div></div>
    <div class="inner"><div>A</div></div>
    <div class="inner"><div>A</div></div>
</div>

<div class="middle" >
    <div class="inner"><div>A</div></div>
    <div class="inner"><div>A</div></div>
    <div class="inner"><div>A</div></div>
    <div class="inner"><div>A</div></div>
    <div class="inner"><div>A</div></div>
    <div class="inner"><div>A</div></div>
    <div class="inner"><div>A</div></div>
</div>

<div class="middle" >
    <div class="inner"><div>A</div></div>
    <div class="inner"><div>A</div></div>
    <div class="inner"><div>A</div></div>
    <div class="inner"><div>A</div></div>
</div>


<div class="middle" >
    <div class="inner"><div>A</div></div>
    <div class="inner"><div>A</div></div>
</div>
```